# Updating multiple struct members without arrays

Tags: c, struct

I am working on a program with the description as follows:

Write a proper C program that makes use of a function to accept user inputs and updates members of a structure. The structure should contain three members: LastName,Gender and Age. LastName will not exceed 30 characters.  The program and function should be flexible enough to with any number of structure members.

The structure instances should be created in the main function. The function should be called for each instance to populate the instance members. The assigned values of the members should be displayed in the main function.

The input and output should work for any number of instances. However for testing purpose, make this work for two structure instances.

Do not create any arrays. The main program and functions should be streamlined (minimum number of variables, avoid temporary variables)

I can't use arrays so I've gone with the following code option. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct member {
    char lastName[30];
    char gender;
    int age;
};

void populateStruct(struct member person);

// begin main function
int main(void){

    int i=0;
    struct member person1={0};
    struct member person2={0};

    populateStruct(person1);
    populateStruct(person2);

    return 0;
} // end main


// function prototypes
void populateStruct(struct member person){

    printf("\nEnter last name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &person.lastName); 
    printf("\nEnter gender: ");
    scanf(" %c", &person.gender);
    printf("\nEnter age: ");
    scanf(" %d", &person.age);

    printf("The information you entered is:\n"); 
    printf("\n"); 
    printf(" %s ", person.lastName);
    printf(" %c ", person.gender);
    printf(" %d ", person.age);
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Have you covered `malloc` and dynamic allocation in your class? Ideally, you would like to create a block of memory large enough to hold two-struct and have the ability to `realloc` when you have filled both.

Comment: Your code is fine, apart from the type error in `scanf(" %s", &person.lastName);` and the fact that `populateStruct` doesn't work. See also: "*The assigned values of the members should be displayed in the main function.*"

Comment: You must mean passing the struct *by value* so that the function receives a copy of the struct and any modifications made in the function will be lost when the function returns. Perhaps passing the address in `main` and the function receiving a pointer may help.

Comment: @chux you are right I apologize I was getting downvotes and thought my question might be too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't printing in the `main` function as the requirements state.  Before you can do that however, you need to pass a *pointer* to your struct to the function.  Right now, you pass a *copy* of your struct to the function, so changes you make in the function aren't visible in `main`.

By passing a pointer, the calling function can **dereference** that pointer to change the object in `main`.

```
void populateStruct(struct member *person);

int main(void){

    int i=0;
    struct member person1={0};
    struct member person2={0};

    populateStruct(&person1);
    populateStruct(&person2);

    printf("The information you entered is:\n"); 
    printf("\n"); 
    printf(" %s ", person1.lastName);
    printf(" %c ", person1.gender);
    printf(" %d ", person1.age);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n"); 
    printf(" %s ", person2.lastName);
    printf(" %c ", person2.gender);
    printf(" %d ", person2.age);
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
} // end main


// function prototypes
void populateStruct(struct member *person){

    printf("\nEnter last name: ");
    scanf(" %29s", person->lastName); 
    printf("\nEnter gender: ");
    scanf(" %c", &person->gender);
    printf("\nEnter age: ");
    scanf(" %d", &person->age);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out how to get the pointer to work. -> looks interesting I will research it now.